# Why is form-getData() empty? (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

There is a HTML form, whish contains an email and password field. I would like to send it to my Controller action using POST.

It only works, if I access the inputs using `$request->request->get('email')`

This code doesn't works. `$data` is an empty object for some reason:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('pass', 'text')
        ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
$data = $form->getData();

return new Response('email: '.$data['email']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$form->get('email')->getData();
```

in your twig template:

```
<form action="{{ path('path-to-controller') }}" method="POST">
{{ form_widget }}
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the form does not expect `email` as POST parameter.

If you are creating the form inputs manually you should render the form in twig first to know the correct form input field names.